# Angular 2 Material - How To Center Progress Spinner

Tags: css, angular, angular2-material

I have implemented the Angular 2 progress spinner from the below link

https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/progress-spinner

I would like to have it centered, however, the only way I can seem to get it to work is to remove the

```
display: block
```

from the CSS. However, this causes the spinner to appear huge on the page.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

just add margin rule:

```
<md-progress-spinner style="margin:0 auto;" 
                     mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-spinner>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sEiTZt830ZE7rqjq9YXO?p=preview

**UPDATE**

Just wanted to share and demonstrate 6 other general centering solutions

- FLEX:

```css
.center {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
}


/* +++++++ STYLES +++++++ */
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  background: red;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center">
  <div class="inner">INNER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

- GRID:

```css
.center {
  display: grid; 
  place-items: center;
}


/* +++++++ STYLES +++++++ */
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  background: red;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center">
  <div class="inner">INNER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

- LINE HEIGHT + TEXT ALIGN (will not work as desired for multiple lines, use white-space: nowrap; to ensure one line)

```css
.center {
  line-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  text-align: center;
}


/* +++++++ STYLES +++++++ */
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center">
  <div class="inner">INNER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

- USING ABSOLUTE, TOP, LEFT and TRANSFORM TRANSLATE

```css
.center.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.center .inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* +++++++ STYLES +++++++ */
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  background: red;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center">
  <div class="inner">INNER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

- USING ABSOLUTE, TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, RIGHT and MARGIN AUTO (mentioned by György Balássy). Note: inner div width needs to be set.

```css
.center.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.center .inner {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  margin: auto;
}


/* +++++++ STYLES +++++++ */
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  background: red;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center">
  <div class="inner">INNER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

- Using TABLE

```css
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* +++++++ STYLES +++++++ */
.wrapper {
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  width: calc(100vw - 20px);;
  background: red;
}
.inner {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper center">
  <div class="inner">INNER CONTENT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works. I am not really good in CSS but how can you achieve this using flexbox?

Comment: You can center any element by adding wrapper div with style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;". You can practice flex at http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Comment: or with css: mat-spinner {
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

Answer (score 55):

This CodePen helped me to create a page-centered spinner with Material Design in Angular 4: https://codepen.io/MattIn4D/pen/LiKFC

Component.html:

```
<div class="loading-indicator">
  <mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate" color="accent"></mat-progress-spinner>
</div>
```

Component.css:

```
/* Absolute Center Spinner */
.loading-indicator {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  overflow: show;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Transparent Overlay */
.loading-indicator:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: First solution is not center vertically but your solution is perfect for it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

The first answer doesn't work unless height is set in a parent element.

I fixed it using fxFlex

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" style="height:100%">
        <mat-spinner diameter="50" strokeWidth="5"></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems the only thing needed is `fxLayoutAlign="center"`.

Answer (score 3):

I am using angular 6 with material 2+ and used that CSS code:

```
.mat-spinner {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to say `margin-right: 50%` as well. You only have to use `margin-left: 50%`

Comment: @Corné Then you should `transform: translateX(-50%)`, or it won't be perfectly centered.

Answer (score 2):

**Source**: [Angular Wiki](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/creating-progress-spinner-in-angular/#how-to-center-mat-progress-spinner)

For me, this worked the best:

Component:

```
<div class="center">
    <mat-spinner> </mat-spinner>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
/** Can be used to center any element */
.center {
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use with grid as well :

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid; 
  place-content: center; 
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  background: red;
}
```